# What is the best solution? Scan

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a string like: `@" ololo width: 350px jijiji width:440px ... text=12... "`
And i want to replace all numbers after @"width: " to the 280. So after scanning, it should be:

```
@" ololo width: 280px jijiji width: 280px ... text=12... "
```

What is the best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
NSString *string = @" ololo width: 350px jijiji width:440px ... text=12... ";
NSMutableString *replaced = [string mutableCopy];

NSString *pattern = @"(width:\\s*)(\\d+)(px)";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                       options:0
                                                                         error:NULL];
[regex replaceMatchesInString:replaced options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, replaced.length)
                 withTemplate:@"$1280$3"];
```

The pattern has three "capturing groups":

- The first matches the string "width:", optionally followed by some white space,
- the second matches one or more digits,
- the third matches the string "px".

The first and the third capturing group are preserved (`$1`, `$3`
in the replacement template), and the second one is replaced by 280.

---

*(Update according to your comments:)* If you need the matched strings
("350", "440") as well
then it is slightly more complicated. Instead of `replaceMatchesInString:`
you can use `enumerateMatchesInString:`:

```
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:replaced
                        options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [replaced length])
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
             // range = location of the regex capture group "(\\d+)":
             NSRange range = [result rangeAtIndex:2];
             // Get old width:
             NSString *oldWidth = [replaced substringWithRange:range];
             NSLog(@"old width=%@", oldWidth);
             // Replace with new width :
             NSString *newWidth = @"280";
             [replaced replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:newWidth];
         }
 ];
```

Comment: what if i need to store 350 and 440? How can i get these values?

Comment: @user3336098: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: sorry for that. I mean, i need to store old data: NSString *oldWidth=@"350";  and then change it to 280.

Comment: but how can i get all the old widths?